# How to set custom path when using New-AzureStorageContext

Tags: powershell, azure-storage

I am copying some files to azure blob storage. I am following Microsoft docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/new-azurestoragecontainersastoken and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/new-azurestoragecontext to create a SAS token. I have the code working but I can't figure out how to set a custom path for URL that New-AzureStorageContext generates, because I would like to copy to a particular path and not the container root. Is there some sort of flag or something for New-AzureStorageContext that will allow me to set this?

```
# Set AzStorageContext
$destinationContext = New-AzureStorageContext -ConnectionString "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxx;AccountKey=xxx;EndpointSuffix=xxx;"

# Generate SAS URI
$containerSASURI = New-AzureStorageContainerSASToken -Context $destinationContext -ExpiryTime(get-date).AddSeconds(3600) -FullUri -Name "xxx" -Permission rw -Protocol HttpsOnly
```

My issue is that New-AzureStorageContainerSASToken generates a URL the I use for azure copy destination `azcopy copy "xxx" $containerSASURI` but it copies to the container root and I would like it to copy to a specific directory e.g \test\demo

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: I have updated to include code used now

Comment: Thanks. I am still not understanding the problem you're facing. How are you copying the files currently? What changes would you like to see there? Please edit your question and include those as well.

Comment: I have updated my question to include how I am copying files and what I would like to see. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. So essentially what you want to do is upload files from your local computer to a blob container but you would want the blobs to go in a specific virtual folder and not at the root of the container.

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're manually copying the Container SAS URL from PowerShell and using it in azcopy, simplest would be to insert the path in the SAS URL.

For example, if your Container SAS URL looks something like:

```
https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container-name?sv=2020-08-04&se=2021-10-04T18%3A30%3A00Z&sr=c&sp=w&sig={signature}
```

and you want to upload the files in `test/demo` folder inside this container, you will change this SAS URL to something like:

```
https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container-name/test/demo?sv=2020-08-04&se=2021-10-04T18%3A30%3A00Z&sr=c&sp=w&sig={signature}
```

and use that in azcopy. All the files are then uploaded into `test/demo` folder inside `container-name` blob container.